# Naive Bayes prediction in R with reading characters as factors and without factors

Tags: r, naivebayes

I'm trying to use Naive bayes on [Mushroom Data set](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Mushroom). Data set is `8124*23` with first column as response variable `{'edible','poisonous'}`. I've eliminated missing data. Final, data set is `5644*23`. Below is the code I've used.

```
mushroom.data <- read.csv("mushroom.data",header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#mushroom.data <- read.csv("mushroom.data",header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

#Eliminating missing data
mushroom.data <- subset(mushroom.data,mushroom.data$V12 != '?')
# Factoring target class
mushroom.data$V1 <- as.factor(mushroom.data$V1)
# First 4000 records as Training set. 
mushroom.train.class <- mushroom.data[1:4000,1]
mushroom.train.data <- mushroom.data[1:4000,-1]
# Building naive bayes classifier
nb.model <- naiveBayes(mushroom.train.data,mushroom.train.class,laplace = 1)
# Last 1644 are Test records
mushroom.test.data <- mushroom.data[4001:5644,-1]
mushroom.test.class <- mushroom.data[4001:5644,1]
# Predicition
nb.pred <- predict(nb.model,mushroom.test.data)
# checking proportions of the predictions
prop.table(table(nb.pred))
```

The model is predicting everything into `edible class` with stringAsFactors = FALSE with accuracy 10-15% and with stringAsFactors = TRUE the accuracy is 91%. What is happening with factoring?

Edit 1: Changed the title. Original problem was solved.

Comment: Can you provide a small subset of data which demonstrates this problem?

Comment: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mushroom/agaricus-lepiota

Comment: This link doesnt work!

Comment: Please include all the relevant code in this post. Water down your example to a few lines of data. Once you get that working, perhaps you can start adding variables and data and see what might be the cause of this.

Comment: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mushroom/agaricus-lepiota.data @ChirayuChamoli

Comment: @krishna This works fine for me.i get e 0.1490268 p 0.8509732 for prop.table(table(nb.pred)).

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli Are you getting any warnings after prediction ? I'm still getting the same  results as e-1, p - 0. https://www.dropbox.com/s/pxnxvlds6lduddt/Image%201.jpg?dl=0

Comment: No warnings for me. Also try loading the data directly using f <-file("https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/mushroom/agaricus-lepiota.data", open="r")
data <- read.table(f, sep=",", header=F)

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli : This worked for me. What could be the problem when trying to read from local disk ? Even i replaced entire data set and tried it again.

Comment: when i removed stringAsFactors it worked. Thanks Bro.

Comment: @krishna No prob. Let me check on the accuracy part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't model character with NaiveBayes. Check ?NaiveBayes and look out for arguments section.